# Table type columns in database

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-types

Can I create a table with table type or user defined table type columns? 
When I try I have this error. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCCY8.jpg)

Comment: Short answer - no.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is tagged `SQL` which means the question relates to the ISO SQL standard (hover over the tag and read what it says).

The SQL standard allows various ways of defining user-defined types (and use those types as the types of columns in base tables).

The SQL standard also allows expressions that yield tables with columns whose type is itself a table (for which purpose you'll be using the COLLECT operator).  As a consequence, it is also possible to define views with columns whose type is itself a table.  And since SQL is aimed at treating views just like base tables as much as possible, the technical answer to your question is "yes, SQL can define tables with table-typed columns" but the proviso is "as long as you define those tables as views on other ones" because SQL won't allow doing that in "genuine" base tables.  AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend existing types and make custom ones. I suggest you give this article from Microsoft Docs a look.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-type-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Example

```
CREATE TYPE SSN  
FROM varchar(11) NOT NULL ;
```

You're able to do more advanced ones also.

Comment: I know I can create user-defined-types; but I want to create a table or view which's column/columns is/are also a table or user-defined-table-types.

Comment: Yes, you can do that with this.